# .incbin error when using it in inline asm

Tags: assembly, binary, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

I am trying to include a binary file on a section of flash by using .incbin as below, but I am getting an error:

```
extern uint8_t _binary_AUDIO_start[];
extern uint8_t _binary_AUDIO_end;
__asm__( \
 ".section \".text.$APP\", \"a\", @progbits\n\t" \
 "_binary_AUDIO_start:\n\t" \
 ".incbin \"" AudioData.bin "\"\n\t" \
 "_binary_AUDIO_end:\n\t" \
 ".previous\n\t" \
);
```

When I compile it I get the following error:

```
audio.c:87:16: error: expected ':' or ')' before 'AudioData'
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? - I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: This redundant quoting is really hard to read.  Why don't you put this in an assembly file instead of using inline assembly? I think your problem is that you have an extra pair of quotes around `AudioData.bin`.

Comment: You could also use `objcopy` or `objconv` with the right args to turn a "flat binary" (`AudioData.bin`) into a `.o` directly, using command line options instead of `.section`.  (I don't know the details off the top of my head, but google and/or check the manual.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I managed to fixed the error related to .incbin line (there were extra quotes indeed), however now I have an error with the .section line: can't resolve `.text.$APP' {.text.$SPIFI_APP section}.

Comment: By the way I am developing on Windows and unfortunately need a solution usi g. incbin.